# SEDE thinks I'm running 2 queries at once

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was just told that I can't run another query:

[image]

> Too many queries are running, you may only run 2 queries at a time

But I was only running one. Why did it tell  me this?
Does running one for Stack Overflow count as 2?

Comment: Did you cancel one before? Are you logged in?

Comment: Ahh not logged in. Does that limit it to 1?

Answer (score 7):

You can only have a certain number of concurrent tasks running at any given time.

This is the code from the Excute method of the [AsyncQueryRunner.cs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/AsyncQueryRunner.cs#L71)

```
string userTag = user.IsAnonymous ? user.IPAddress : user.Id.ToString();

List<Task> activeTasks;
running.TryGetValue(userTag, out activeTasks);
if (activeTasks != null)
{
    lock(activeTasks)
    {
          if (activeTasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted).Count() >= AppSettings.ConcurrentQueries)
          {
             throw new ApplicationException("Too many queries are running, you may only run " + AppSettings.ConcurrentQueries + " queries at a time");
```

You can cancel your query by hitting the Cancel link in the SEDE web client or start a new query before the running one ended. That might not immediately cancel your runningtask as the queries, if they have not a result yet, run async and the browser polls for the results.

The difference between signed in and anonymous is that when anonymous you are throttled per IP-address. In either case the number of concurrent queries is using the same config setting which is 2 at the moment.